# How to generate a dynamic file name for a mysqldump on Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to schedule my MySql backs to happen on an hourly basis, but the problem is I want to customize the name of the file that is outputs but not to sure how to?

This is the command I am using now

```
mysqldump -u yourusername -h yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com 'yourusername$dbname'  > db-backup.sql
```

This works but I would to have it output a file something like this, but for it to happen dynamically, when the command is run

```
1-01-18.13:50.db-backup.sql
```

How could I do this on a single line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it :

```
mysqldump -u yourusername -h yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com 'yourusername$dbname'  > `date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M"`.db-backup.sql
```

Will generate files like : `2018-01-01_13-50.db-backup.sql`. You can adapt this to whatever exact format you want (but you should avoid using special characters such as `:`).

If you want to compress the file on the fly :

```
mysqldump -u yourusername -h yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com 'yourusername$dbname'  | gzip > `date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M"`.db-backup.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$()` and `date`.

```
mysqldump -u yourusername -h yourusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com 'yourusername$dbname' > "$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S).db-backup.sql"
```

The format specifiers of your `date` might vary, refer the man page for details.